# Windows: Issue coming when running multiple commands in 1 line, and not when running then one by one

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

When running following command on windows command line, issue is coming:

```
set P4USER=ARPIT & set P4PORT=opl:p4dia:1934 & set P4CLIENT=opl_reg_591 & p4 client -o
```

Error:

```
Perforce client error:
        Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
        The specified class was not found.
```

But when running these command, one by one, on cmd, no issue is coming:

```
set P4USER=ARPIT 
set P4PORT=opl:p4dia:1934
set P4CLIENT=opl_reg_591
p4 client -o
```

Why so?

I want to run these 4 mini commands in 1 line, as I have to use them in a backtick in a script. How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: make a `.bat` file and use back-tics to run that? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, not working, and backticks doesn't work in batch file

Comment: added a `batch-file` tag, maybe the batch-file people will see this and help out. Good luck.

Comment: Try `set "P4USER=ARPIT"` for each of the variables being set. Your current syntax includes the space before the `&` into the value assigned. Quoting as shown makes the assignment required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Magoo answer (`set "P4USER=ARPIT" for each of the variables being set. Your current syntax includes the space before the & into the value assigned. Quoting as shown makes the assignment required`) is right.

Also, the following can be used in this context:

```
p4 -u ARPIT -c opl_reg_591 -p opl:p4dia:1934 client -o
```